# jQuery DatePicker append text beforeShow and onSelect

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, calendar

Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dw6Ldbfj/)

The first Calendar is what I currently have, I wanted to add some text element at the bottom of the calendar inside the div `.ui-datepicker`

I have this code which doesn't work properly,

```
(function($) {
     $('.date').datepicker({
        beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
            alert('Show it to me baby');
            $(this).find('.ui-datepicker').append( 'Here I am' );
        },
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var date = $(this).val();
            alert( date ); 
            $(this).find('.ui-datepicker').append( date );
        }
    }); 
})(jQuery);
```

my problems are

1. The beforeShow method doesn't work for calendar that is being displayed on pageload, it works fine when datepicker is attached to input.
2. In the event "onSelect", it looks like the calendar HTML element has been re added in dom and my append code won't run on the current calendar,

I would appreciate any guidance,

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, in the [jQuery UI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI) DatePicker API, it's said

```
**beforeShow**
Type: Function( Element input, Object inst )
Default: null
A function that takes an input field and current datepicker instance and returns an options object to update the datepicker with. It is called just before the datepicker is displayed.
```

For your second question, if you do this, it will work:

```
$(this).append(date);
```

Comment: yeah, I'm aware of that, that's why I wanted to know if there's a solution for calendar not being attached on input. 
and yes, this code ```$(this).append(date);``` should work fine,  I can even append any element on the div I will define, but that's not going to work as I need to append the element inside ```ui-datepicker-inline ui-datepicker``` div for styling for purposes, that would only be my last option if I can't find a solution